# Simplify winforms code cross thread calls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, optimization, invoke

I'm developing a cross-thread application which have some methods within `Invoke`:

```
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        pbTotalProgress.Value = progress;
        labe1.Text="SomeText";
    }));
}
else
{
    pbTotalProgress.Value = progress;
    labe1.Text="SomeText";
}
```

How can I write the code below a bit shorter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should, at the least, only define the action once (don't have the code again in the else branch, just run the action there without the invoke.
You could also write an extension method for control that runs an Action as an invoke if required or just runs it. That would get rid of the complexity from your event handler and you will end up using the same pattern for many events in your application.

```
static class ControlExtensions
{
  public static void InvokeOrExecute(this Control control, Action action)
  {
     if (control.InvokeRequired)
     {
        control.Invoke(action);
     }
     else
     {
        action();
     }
  }
}
```

Then in each event that could be cross thread:

```
Action setProgress = delegate()
     {
        pbTotalProgress.Value = progress;
        labe1.Text = "SomeText";
     };
this.InvokeOrExecute(setProgress);
```

Comment: This is so easy, literally copy and pasting it and it works. This can be used for a variety of things, not only progress. (input from a serial port for example)
Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's the same block of code, you could set it in an `Action` variable and `Invoke`/execute it. Try something like:

```
Action setProgress = delegate() {
    pbTotalProgress.Value = progress;
    labe1.Text = "SomeText";
};
if (this.InvokeRequired) {
    this.Invoke(setProgress);
} else {
    setProgress();
}
```

Your exact code doesn't really need optimization. The only thing that is happening is you're performing a conditional-check on a boolean flag `this.InvokeRequired`. If anything, my answer only provides the ability to write the Action-code once instead of duplicating it.